# How to destruct a complex object

Tags: react-native

One of my functions returns the object below:

```
Promise {
    {
        user: {
          name: 'Ervin Howell',
          email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
          type: 'authenticated'
        }
      }
}
```

How to destruct user object from this json?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain what you mean by destruct? Are you referring to [unpacking a value from a dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can read the JSON API in this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). it has two methods:`JSON.parse` and `JSON.sringify`.
for your situation, you can use `JSON.parse` if your function return a JSON string

```
let json = "{
    user: {
      name: 'Ervin Howell',
      email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
      type: 'authenticated'
    }
  }
}"
obj = JSON.parse(json);

// when you want the user object
let user = obj.user
// when you want the user's name
let name = user.name
```